# invalid conversion const unsigned char

Tags: c++

I have this function in my program:

```
unsigned char * stringXOR(const unsigned char * X, const unsigned char * Y, int len)
{
    unsigned char * result = new unsigned char [1024];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        result[i] = X[i] ^ Y[i];
    }
    result[len] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

in main():

```
unsigned char ot1[1024] = "ksjdhsjd";
unsigned char ot2[1024] = "jjjkjhyh";

unsigned char * computeKey;
computeKey = stringXOR(ot1, ot2, strlen(ot1));
```

and i get an error `invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]|`

what is the problem here? i am not returning any const so what is is complaining about ?

Comment: Always provide the line the error occured at.

Comment: Read up how `strlen` is specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strlen` expects `const char *`. You are trying to pass `const unsigned char *` to it. This is what the error message is about.

Comment: oh, so i have to cast it everytime i use strlen with something else that const char *

Comment: @lllook, *something else than `const char*`*  - you shouldn't be using `strlen` for anything other than `char*` or `const char*`.

Answer (score 2):

The error is not about any conversion to `const`, it's about converting a pointer to `unsigned char` to a pointer to a (const)`char *`.